# Drupal 7: Create a taxonomy term for each node and use the node title as the term name

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

Is there anyway of doing this by using rules or by some custom code?
I did try using rules but I can't find a way of adding a new term and set the name as the node title because the [node:title] token is not avilable.

I know this is possible using the [NAT](http://drupal.org/project/nat) module but the way this module changes the taxonomy terms hierarchy if you add a term reference field that uses the same taxonomy vocabulary which ruins the whole purpose of what I am trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Creating a new term for each node is not a good practise.

Comment: its only for a certain content type which is actually working as a book outline (book module) but book doesnt allow you to relate books with other books so my idea for overcoming this was to have a taxonomy term for each book and use a term reference field. 
I wasnt aware of a node reference field so i'm away to look into it.

Comment: Yeah node reference is your guy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I would have two suggestions:

- In Drupal 7, you can create fields per vocabulary, so perhaps it would be more interesting for you to create "`one term with fields`" instead of creating "`one node with fields + one term`" each time ?
- Otherwise, whatever entity needs to reference your node thru its matching taxonomy term could directly reference the node instead (using a "`Node Reference`" field), that way you  wouldn't need to maintain a separated vocabulary in parallel of your list of nodes.

But if you still want to create one term per node, then you should use the hooks that Haza mentioned.

Comment: two good ways of looking at it i'll have a look at both and get back to u. A node reference field sounds exactly like what i need. I didnt know this existed, thanks

Comment: By the way, the Drupal-specialized section of Stackoverflow (http://drupal.stackexchange.com) has open its beta a few days ago, it may be interesting for you.

Comment: Thank you v much, for the answer and for the link. I had a further question on this topic which I posted on drupal forums [here](http://drupal.org/node/1088446) but im not sure if this stackoverflow section is only for developers or for general use as well?

Comment: It's for both as long as it's Drupal-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Using [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) you are able to add some operations when a node is saved.

As long as you have all the node informations when you are at this step, there no real difficulties to create a taxonomy term at the same time.

Be aware that there is also a [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example--nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_update/7) function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite as simple as the above posts would have you believe. If you want functionality that just keeps a term name and node title in sync, try the NAT module. Although I had to write my own module to do what your op is asking.

Building out a term with what would be the node fields doesn't work if you're using taxonomy to build a graphical structure of all your content (kind of like RDF). Sure, you could have a new vocabulary bundle for every content type you want, but functions like

```
taxonomy_get_parents_all()
taxonomy_get_tree()
```

were written with single vocabularies in mind and with a different pointing system (references vs whatever the relationships field is called in a term - sets parent(s))

As limited as core taxonomy functions are with respect to inter-vocabulary relationships, it's still a heck of a lot better than what og or references have. Relation module is ideal but there's almost nada in the way of community support so far. Relation should go into core imo.